imputing NA with combination of previous values without loop
continuing on last question, i need to impute missing last couple of years as combination of previous years in R. In the data below, i need to impute 2020 as linear combination of 2019,2018 and 2017, and thene 2021 as combination of 2020, 2019, 2018.
> comb1 <- cbind(CJ(letters[1:4], 2000:2019), rnorm(80,2,1)) 
> comb2 <-  cbind(CJ(letters[1:4], 2020:2024), data.frame(rep(NA, 20)))
> colnames(comb1) <- c("state","year","v")
> colnames(comb2) <- c("state","year","v")
> 
> comb <- rbind(comb1, comb2)
> comb <- comb[order(comb$state, comb$year),]
>

I can do it in a loop (below) but it it very slow as my data is large (i have many "states"). Does someone know how to do it in more efficient way?
> library(dplyr)
> vlist <- unique(comb$state)
> for (i in vlist) {
> for (j in (2002:2024)) {
> value <- 0.65*comb$v[comb$year==j-1 & comb$stat==i] + 0.25*comb$v[comb$year==j-2 & comb$state==i] + 0.10*comb$v[comb$year==j-3 & comb$state==i]
> if (is.na(comb$v[comb$year==j & comb$state==i])) {
> comb$v[comb$year==j & comb$state==i] <- value
>     }
>   }
> }
> 

I managed to do it partially by vectors so is faster, but more elegant solution would be nice though...
for (j in (2002:2024)) {
  
  comb$v_1 <- ave(comb$v, comb$state, FUN = dplyr::lag)
  comb$v_2 <- ave(comb$v_1, comb$state, FUN = dplyr::lag) 
  comb$v_3 <- ave(comb$v_2, comb$state, FUN = dplyr::lag) 
  
  comb$imp <- 0.65*comb$v_1 + 0.25*comb$v_2 + 0.10*comb$v_3
  comb$v <- ifelse(is.na(comb$v)&comb$year==j, comb$imp, comb$v)
  
 comb$v_1 <- NULL
 comb$v_2 <- NULL
 comb$v_3 <- NULL
 comb$imp <- NULL
}


A bit convoluted, but does the trick:
First, create a simple function to calculate the value to be imputed, from the last three numbers on a vector:
impute <- function(x) {
  sum(tail(x, 3) * c(0.1, 0.25, 0.65))
}

Then another simple function that calls this function whenever an NA is found (or just moves forward along the vector):
roll_impute <- function(x, y) {
  if (is.na(x)) {
    c(x, impute(x))
  } else {
    c(x, y)
  }
}

Now just use reduce() from the purrr package to recursively apply this function to v.  Since you want this to work separately per state, we group the data.frame beforehand:
comb %>%
  group_by(state) %>%
  mutate(v = reduce(v, roll_impute))

Edit:
The first two steps can obviously be simplified into:
roll_impute <- function(x, y) {
  if (is.na(x)) {
    c(x, sum(tail(x, 3) * c(0.1, 0.25, 0.65)))
  } else {
    c(x, y)
  }
}

Also, running microbenchmark on a larger set (26 states) shows the speedup is about 14-fold, on average:
library(microbenchmark)

method_a <- function(comb) {
  vlist <- unique(comb$state)
    for (i in vlist) {
      for (j in (2002:2024)) {
        value <- 0.65*comb$v[comb$year==j-1 & comb$stat==i] + 0.25*comb$v[comb$year==j-2 & comb$state==i] + 0.10*comb$v[comb$year==j-3 & comb$state==i]
        if (is.na(comb$v[comb$year==j & comb$state==i])) {
          comb$v[comb$year==j & comb$state==i] <- value
        }
      }
    }
  comb
}

method_b <- function(comb) {
    comb %>%
    group_by(state) %>%
    mutate(v = reduce(v, roll_impute))
}

comb <-
  bind_rows(
    expand.grid(state = letters, year = 2000:2019, stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
    mutate(v = rnorm(nrow(.))),
    expand.grid(state = letters, year = 2020:2024, stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
      mutate(v = NA)
  )

microbenchmark(method_a(comb), method_b(comb))

Unit: milliseconds
           expr       min        lq       mean    median         uq        max neval cld
 method_a(comb) 60.616898 61.250113 110.456925 61.890937 177.375896 317.968330   100  a
 method_b(comb)  7.357221  7.473352   7.943528  8.070393   8.240969   9.690326   100   b

